# robotino-ros package

Tags: ros, roslaunch, robotino, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

i using the robotino with kinetic . I use the following robotino package [from this source](http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/) for my project. I started the with **roslaunch robotino_node robotino_node.launch** and than i get some error in my launch file.

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_node]: can't locate node [robotino_node] in package 
[robotino_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_odometry_node]: can't locate node [robotino_odometry_node] in package [robotino_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_laserrangefinder_node]: can't locate node [robotino_laserrangefinder_node] in package [robotino_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_camera_node]: can't locate node [robotino_camera_node] in package [robotino_node]
process[robot_state_publisher-6]: started with pid [2608]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_mapping_node]: can't locate node [robotino_mapping_node] in package [robotino_node]
```

robotino_node.launch-file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="hostname" default="172.26.1.1" />
  
    <node name="robotino_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_node" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
        <param name="max_linear_vel" value="0.5" />
        <param name="min_linear_vel" value="0.05" />
        <param name="max_angular_vel" value="3.0" />
        <param name="min_angular_vel" value="0.1" />
        <param name="downsample_kinect" value="true" />
        <param name="leaf_size_kinect" value="0.04" />
        <remap from="robotino_joint_states" to="joint_states" />
        <!--remap from="image_raw" to="image"/-->
    </node>

  <node name="robotino_odometry_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_odometry_node" output="screen">
    <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
  </node>

  <node name="robotino_laserrangefinder_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_laserrangefinder_node" output="screen">
    <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
    <param name="laserRangeFinderNumber" value="0" />
  </node>

  <node name="robotino_camera_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_camera_node" output="screen">
    <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
    <param name="cameraNumber" value="0" />
  </node>


    <!--<node pkg="robotino_switch" type="robotino_switch_node" name="robotino_switch" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
    </node>-->

    
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="20.0" />
    </node>
    
  <node name="robotino_mapping_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_mapping_node" output="screen">
    <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
  </node>
    <!--node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_link_broadcaster" args="0.12 0 0.025 0 0 0 base_link laser_link 50" /-->
    
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robotino_description)/urdf/robotino.urdf" />
</launch>
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?
Please let me know, when you need more information about this problem.

regards,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318924/robotino-ros-package/) by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i forgot to source my workspace --> source robotino_ws/devel/setup.bash

That solve my problem

---

Originally posted by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) with karma: 54 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0